# How to make an exception in a pattern rule in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

My makefile has the following rule for creation of object files :

`%.o: %.c

            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(INCPATH) -I$(INC_DIR) $< -o $@`

But I want another rule for my main.o. Is there a way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your specific rule. If it already exists, pattern matching wouldn't happen for it.

Comment: Pretty simple! Thanks :)